# How to prevent user from dropping shulker box?

Tags: kotlin, maven, plugins, minecraft

I'm currently developing a new plugin for my minecraft server.
I had this code:

```kotlin
    @EventHandler
    fun onPlayerDropItem(event: PlayerDropItemEvent) {
        // Record the timestamp when a player drops an item
        droppedItemTimestamp[event.player] = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }

    private fun isShulkerBox(item: ItemStack): Boolean {
        return item.type in shulkerBoxTitles.keys
    }
```

So basically I want to prevent user from dropping the shulker box (any kind of shulker box) when they are holding it on their hand. Otherwise, allow them to drop it.

I tried:

```kotlin
@EventHandler
fun onPlayerDropItem(event: PlayerDropItemEvent) {
    val player = event.player
    val droppedItem = event.itemDrop.itemStack

    // Check if the dropped item is a shulker box
    if (isShulkerBox(droppedItem)) {
        val mainHandItem = player.inventory.itemInMainHand
        val offHandItem = player.inventory.itemInOffHand

        // Check if the player is holding the shulker box in either hand
        if (mainHandItem == droppedItem || offHandItem == droppedItem) {
            event.isCancelled = true // Cancel the item drop event
            player.sendMessage(format("§cYou can't drop the shulker box you are holding!"))
        }
    }

    // Record the timestamp when a player drops any item
    droppedItemTimestamp[player] = System.currentTimeMillis()
}
```

But it didn't work, can anyone help me? Just dont mess with my timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to check for the item in either hand. Just check whether the the dropped item is a shulkerbox or not (as you are doing)
2. We don't see your ShulkerBoxTitles.keys, so it might be error there.
3. Make sure the plugin is running and the listener is properly registered.

Comment: The plugin does work and it is running perfectly. the ShulkerBoxTitles.keys contains every single shulker box inside the map so it's not the case. Check my full code: https://github.com/hoangxuanlam2007/BaloShulker/blob/master/src/main/java/me/hoangxuanlam2007/baloshulker/BaloShulker.kt

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the inventory is updated before the PlayerDropEvent is called. So the condition `mainHandItem == droppedItem || offHandItem == droppedItem` will always evaluate to false when a player drop an item from his hotbar.

You could try to do some tricks to bypass that limitation but there is no clean way to handle that, you better have to find a solution to solve your problem that does not involve allowing to drop only non held item.